# Using HTML datalist element with VueJS? Can't use hyperlinks?

Tags: vuejs2, html-datalist

I am trying to use HTML's `datalist` [https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp] element rather than an autocompletion library. I tried to wrap an a href element around the `post.title`.

Unfortunately, it looks like this is not possible with the datalist's option element?

> Here's my template:

```
<input v-model='post' type='text' list='posts'>
        <datalist id='posts'>
            <option v-for='post in posts' :key='post.id'>
                <a :href='url + `${post.id}`'>{{post.title}}</a>
            </option>
        </datalist>
```

> Script:

```
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "SearchBar",
  data() {
    return {
      post: "",
      posts: [],
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/",
      //placeholder: "Search or jump to item"
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.getPosts();
  },
  methods: {
    getPosts() {
      axios
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          this.posts = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
};
```

Anyone got some workarounds for this? Thank you

Comment: OK, so it seems like I was trying to reinvent the wheel here...just need to find a good Vue Autocompletion script.

Answer (score 1):

friend.
if you want to check.
regards!
Here's [a link](https://jsfiddle.net/juanvqz/sy4qubfh/7/)!

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      posts: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getPosts()
  },
  methods: {
    getPosts() {
      axios
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          this.posts = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input list="posts" name="posts">
  <datalist id="posts">
    <option v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id" :value="post.title">
      <a href="google.com">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </option>
  </datalist>
</div>
```